# How should I use extglob in Python fabric?

Tags: python, bash, glob, fabric

I am trying to use fabric (v2.6) to run some commands that make use of bash's extglob and dotglob.

When I run:

```
c.run(f"shopt -s extglob dotglob && rm -Rf {project_path}* !(.|..|.venv) && shopt -u extglob dotglob")
```

I get this error:

```
`bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('`
```

I am using the `&&` because I found doing `shopt -s extglob dotglob` in a separate run call doesn't persist for the subsequent run calls. I'm pretty sure using `&&` is enabling extglob and dotglob because when I do this:

```
`c.run("shopt -s extglob dotglob && shopt")`
```

It prints out the list of options and extglob and dotglob are both enabled.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `extglob` can't be used with Python Fabric unfortunately.

From the [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)

> `extglob` changes the way certain characters are parsed. It is necessary
> to have a **newline** (**not just a semicolon**) between `shopt -s extglob` and
> any subsequent commands to use it.

But from the [Fabric docs](https://www.fabfile.org/faq.html?highlight=environment%20variable#my-cd-workon-export-etc-calls-don-t-seem-to-work)

> While Fabric can be used for many shell-script-like tasks, there’s a
> slightly unintuitive catch: each `run` [...] has **its own distinct shell session**. This is required
> in order for Fabric to reliably figure out, after your command has
> run, what its standard out/error and return codes were.

Fortunately, a similar thing can be achieved using Bash's GLOBIGNORE shell variable instead

> The GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file
> names matching a pattern. If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching file
> name that also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed
> from the list of matches. If the nocaseglob option is set, the
> matching against the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is performed without
> regard to case. The filenames . and .. are always ignored when
> GLOBIGNORE is set and not null. However, setting GLOBIGNORE to a
> non-null value has the effect of enabling the dotglob shell option, so
> all other filenames beginning with a ‘.’ will match. To get the old
> behavior of ignoring filenames beginning with a ‘.’, make ‘.*’ one of
> the patterns in GLOBIGNORE. The dotglob option is disabled when
> GLOBIGNORE is unset.

This also handily ignores `.` and `..` when expanding wildcards, so to remove all files - except '.venv' - in a directory, we can do

```
c.run("GLOBIGNORE='.venv'; rm -Rf {project_path}*")
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the bash wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

> `extglob` changes the way certain characters are parsed. It is necessary to have a newline (not just a semicolon) between `shopt -s extglob` and any subsequent commands to use it.

So you have to change your python code appropriately so that a newline is used instead of `&&`.

Or just do what the bash invocation does directly in python.